# can i use select * from table with inner join and where condition in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

the question is that i want to fetch all the field from different table with inner join and where condition.
I tried this query

```
$nowfire="select *
                from reg_user r
                inner join state s
                on r.state=s.state_id
                inner join country c 
                on r.country= c.country_id
          where email_id='xyz@gmail.com'";
```

i know the another method is like this

```
$nowfire="select r.profile_id, r.email_id,s.state_name, c.city_name
                from reg_user r
                inner join state s
                on r.state=s.state_id
                inner join country c 
                on r.country= c.country_id
           where email_id='xyz@gmail.com'";
```

this is working ...no problem.
but 
can i used like in above frist *select * * ....format...
is this possible in mysqli....please help
Thanks in advance for any help.....

Comment: What are error you got ?

Comment: i am not getting error...i got the output in json format.. but i want to reduce the query...

Comment: I think have some field of three table same name.

Comment: yes the three table having common fields like   reg_user table contains state_id  and state table also contain state_id and so on...                                    but i want only one field i.e. state_name from state not state_id from reg_user also ..                                                                                                  your solution gives both i.e. state_id and state_name..      that was i am not expecting...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$nowfire="select r.*,s.state_name, c.city_name
                from reg_user r
                inner join state s
                on r.state=s.state_id
                inner join country c 
                on r.country= c.country_id
          where email_id='xyz@gmail.com'";
```

Comment: @suresh: If you want output in json format, I think you can select all field of table `reg_user` and some field of other tables that not exist in table `reg_user`.  I had update my answer

Comment: but my table reg_user contains state_id and table state contains state_name                                                                                    i want only name from state table not id from reg_user table.....................is this possible......if i tried your solution i got the fallowing output:                                         {
  "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
  "first_name": "abc",
  "state": "1",
  "marital_status": "never married",
  "mother_tounge": "marathi",
  "religion": "1",
  "state_name": "maharastra",
  "religion_name": "hindu",
}but i want only one field .

Comment: output: { "email_id": "abc@gmail.com", "first_name": "abc", "marital_status": "never married", "mother_tounge": "marathi", "religion": "1", "state_name": "maharastra", "religion_name": "hindu", } i want this format but the query is like menton above...

Answer (score 0):

```
$nowfire="select r.*,s.*, c.*
                from reg_user r
                inner join state s
                on r.state=s.state_id
                inner join country c 
                on r.country= c.country_id
          where email_id='xyz@gmail.com'";
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.